# How can I send this request to another host?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, header, httprequest

When I run the following code on my server and click on the button it sends the request to my own server,

**This is the Request header**

```
GET /dir/api/blah/confirmation HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://myserver.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
```

but what I want is to send the to request another website like `example.com/dir/api/blah/confirmation`.

How can I do it?

**This is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://example.com" method="POST">
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
 
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "confirmation");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full url inside the open method:

```
var url = 'example.com/dir/api/blah/confirmation';
xhttp.open('GET', url)
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

And be careful the CORS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: It changes the directory but not the Host. ```GET /example.com/dir/api/blah/confirmation HTTP /1.1
Host: myserver.com```